# Does pyomo support column generation?

Tags: python, pyomo, column-generation

I want to use column generation technique to solve cutting stock problem.
Is there any other python modeling library that supports column generation?

Comment: remember that when you would like to solve an integer program, you need branch-and-price, not (only) column generation; most frameworks/codes support CG but not the branching -- when you want to solve a cutting stock problem, you can directly use a Python API of any solver and hope for a good integer solution, or you can trry GCG, of course ;) works like a charm on cutting stock

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke you need branch-and-price if you want the optimal solution. If you are willing to sacrifice it (ouch), you can do price-and-branch (column generation followed my a MIP with the columns in the pool). This is what is done in Pulp's examples.

Comment: yes, this is what I meant by "directly use a Python API", which probably works well in many cases; thanks for the comment

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with PuLP. A column wise formulation for the cutting stock problem is given in the [examples](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/examples/CGcolumnwise.py). So you don't have much to do...

However, it would be interesting to see how PuLp compares with Pyomo.